# Android application tutorials activity

Tags: android, bitmap

[image: Applications Tutorials Page]

The following is my instructions page for the application that is being worked upon. For now I am just display this image via the `ImageView` using the `scaleXY` property to make it pan out throughout the screen. I do know that this is a very lame approach to making a tutorials page ... So can someone please tell me how can I correctly implement this tutorials page in my application ? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here looks like it can help you.

You're current method works, but I think you'll find this alternative much more preferable.

> The ShowcaseView library is designed to highlight and showcase specific parts of apps to the user with a distinctive and attractive overlay. This library is great for pointing out points of interest for users, gestures, or obscure but useful items.

https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView